# Запятая перед "чем" ("выше(,) чем где-то")

Tags: грамматика

Возникает вопрос: нужна ли запятая в словосочетании ***"выше(,) чем в Гималаях"***?

Comment: Екатерина, приведите, пожалуйста, полное предложение.

Comment: 1. Какой у Вас интересный вопрос! Мне даже захотелось узнать не только про ГДЕ-ТО, но и про ЧТО-ТО! И про КТО-ТО! Еще мысль пришла про НАДО! 2. Вы написали, что вопрос ВОЗНИКАЕТ! Вследствие чего он возникает? И как? Сам собой? И где? В голове? Вашей?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
  А вы можете придумать примеру без обособления?

Comment: @Sharon  Это я так, как говорится, для проформы, чтобы "лучше видеть [тебя, предложеньице!]".